# How to delete a user in MSCRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Do you know of a way to get rid of CRM User accounts in MSCRM 4.0? After some user accounts have been deleted in AD we're faced a lot of issues while importing the organisation to another server stating that there are issues with the user mapping.

What kind of idea is behind the fact that no user accounts can be deleted from the crm installation? Is there any tool or undocumented Webservice API call to get rid of crm users?

Thanks for sharing yours insights

Comment: For testing purposes it would be cool to have an automatic way to delete users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no working way of actually removing CRM users from the database; I think one reason is that it would cause all the records previously owned by a now deleted user having no owner at all (the same goes for the createdby and modifiedby fields), which would put the database in an illegal state.

The official way of removing a user from the CRM system is deactivating the `systemuser` record. This does not sever the connection to the AD user, however, but I think deactivated users should not cause problems when reimporting the organization; I'm not sure of that, though.

You could theoretically delete the `systemuser` records from the database using SQL, but that's highly unadvisable.

Changes in the AD users are actually causing various issues with MSCRM quite often; a larger customer even had us develop a solution for automatically synchronizing their CRM users with the state of the AD because managing that manually proved to be too much work in a large environment with a few hundred users.

Comment: So the answer is : no. Not a single way.
How are people testing their software if they can't delete their test users before each run?